# xml file vs xml layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I created two layout files.

Android XML Layout File which created this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


</LinearLayout>
```

and an Android XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


</LinearLayout>
```

From the looks of it they are both the same. When to use one over the other since they are both creating the same xml?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah they are prograticaly the same, there isn't different type of xml. What matters, is the location of the xml (layout, values, ...).

In eclipse, there maybe is a small difference in the IDE view, i'm not sure that you have the Graphical Layout view if you create a Android XML file instead of a layout file (it's a detail because, you still can add this view ;) )

But results apk will be identical.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you would use an Android XML, is if you wanted to use the Layout Tool (the GUI layout editor).  The Eclipse IDE will react to this file differently.

But, the code is the same, so the APK you create will also be the same - it doesn't matter in your final output.

I always use Android XML files, so they integrate into the ADT tools better.

Answer (score 0):

the only difference as far as I can see is that in xml you can't use both "android:layout-width:" and "android:layout-height:" attributes which makes xml for example suitable for the use of menu and item bar and other uses.